# Automate pressing Ctrl+V, down arrow, home button

Tags: batch-file, ssis

I would like to write a short script (batch file) to automate pressing three buttons

1. Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> (to paste something).
2. Pressing the <kbd>Down Arrow</kbd>.
3. Pressing the <kbd>Home</kbd> button (to the right of the <kbd>Insert</kbd> button and to the left of the <kbd>PgUp</kbd> button - on most keyboards)

I need to repeat this sequence of pressed buttons 500 times and I wouldn't want to do it by hand.
Anyone has an idea how to do this?

My OS is Windows 7 if it matters. The program that I would be pressing those buttons is SSIS (not sure if it matters).

Comment: you can use a macro to do this if they are available by default or as a 3rd party package.

Comment: I hate to ask this, but what in the world are you doing in SSIS that requires pasting 500 times? I'm willing to wager that using a .NET script is going to be far cleaner than AutoIt or whatever program you use.

Comment: That said, you'll want to update the question to describe the problem at hand. Otherwise, this will likely get VtC as Offtopic due to a request for tool/library.

Comment: Keypress automation should be a last resort.  There is nearly always a better way to accomplish the root issue.

Comment: @billinkc I have a third party component that preforms a checksum operation (hash MD5) on all the columns of each row and uses that to compare rows. Now when I have too many columns it brakes. I think it brakes somewhere around 250 columns wide, but I am not sure. Hence I am trying to construct a test to figure out where it brakes exactly.